# Convert Google Maps north to Magnetic north

Tags: google-maps, geodjango, magnetometer, degrees

I'm building a Django site connected to an android app. The android part is a navigator, and the site permits to build your own maps using images.

During the construction of these maps, user can set the bearing through a rotation of the image of the map on an instance of google maps.

I'm using css to rotate the image, so 0° is the image "as is" and 360° is the image upside down: so the north is "up".

The android app will not use the gps system, so I have to relay on the magnetic field to show the map rotating on user's movements (for detecting the user's movement I have another method, but this is not necessary for the question), and  I found out on [this page](http://googlecompass.com/GoogleMapsProjection.htm) that magnetic north is not that showed in google maps, and that I have to do some corrections to the values, but I don't know how.

Somebody can help me to shift the images's rotation degree to north magnetic degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for magnetic declination values.  First you will need to get your location.  Since you don't have GPS, you will use the NETWORK_PROVIDER location; this will be close enough to get your declination value.

To find out how far and which direction to rotate your images you should use something like [this API](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/declinationHelp) from NOAA.

For example, if you are @  40.000, -105.250 you would make this API call:
    http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?lat1=40&lon1=-105.25&resultFormat=xml

And you would get this in return:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<maggridresult>
    <result>
        <date> 2012.82514 </date>
        <latitude> 40.00000 </latitude>
        <longitude> -105.25000 </longitude>
        <elevation units="km"> 0.00000 </elevation>
        <declination> 8.90399 </declination>
        <declination_sv> -8.01691 </declination_sv>
    </result>
</maggridresult>
```

So you would rotate your map 8.90399°

For reference, [here is a map](http://www.windtesting.com/4.html) showing approximate magnetic declination values.

Comment: Ok, very interesting service. Only one question, can I use the degrees  as angles, adding 8.9° to the value I found out with my system, or I have to do another conversion step?

Comment: The degrees are the same.  There are 360° on the compass, and you have 360° of rotation on your image.

Comment: Background on magnetic declination: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/declination.shtml